# Laravel - MorphTo relation returns null

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, mariadb, polymorphism

I have a polymorphic relationship between an `Article` model and 3 models (`Company`, `Group` & `User`) that sometimes returns `null`.

90% of the time, the articleable relation is perfectly OK and looks like this:

```
#relations: array:1 [▼
    "articleable" => App\Models\User {#1443 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "users"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: false
      #with: array:2 [▶]
      #withCount: []
      +preventsLazyLoading: false
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
      #attributes: array:7 [▶]
      #original: array:7 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #attributeCastCache: []
      #dates: array:1 [▶]
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: array:1 [▶]
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:2 [▶]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: array:2 [▶]
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #rememberTokenName: "remember_token"
    }
  ]
```

But sometimes (1 / 10 ~), the relation is `null`:

```
#relations: array:1 [▼
    "articleable" => null
  ]
```

However, my model's attribute seems perfectly fine:

```
  #attributes: array:8 [▼
    "id" => "e5db380f-9516-491f-bf5d-c13eb2978eac"
    "articleable_type" => "App\Models\User" ←
    "articleable_id" => "20e00040-477b-44c5-800f-629a2380afe3" ←
    "title" => "Between yourself and me.' 'That's the most."
    "content" => "Alice. 'And ever since that,' the Hatter went on, spreading out the verses the White Rabbit interrupted: 'UNimportant, your Majesty means, of course,' the Mock  ▶"
    "image_url" => "https://via.placeholder.com/640x480.png/005511?text=non"
    "created_at" => "2022-07-27 11:51:01"
    "updated_at" => "2022-07-27 11:51:01"
  ]
```

And my DB does have the record (JSON export from my `users` table):

```
[
  {
    "id": "20e00040-477b-44c5-800f-629a2380afe3",
    "email": "carolanne.mayer@example.net",
    "email_verified_at": "2022-07-27 11:51:01",
    "password": "$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi",
    "remember_token": "3gRso464ST",
    "created_at": "2022-07-27 11:51:01",
    "updated_at": "2022-07-27 11:51:01"
  }
]
```

My models look like this:

**User:**

```
  App\Models\User ..........................................
  Database ........................................... mysql
  Table .............................................. users

  Attributes ................................... type / cast
  id unique ..................................... string(36)
  email unique, fillable ....................... string(255)
  email_verified_at nullable, fillable . datetime / datetime
  password fillable, hidden .................... string(255)
  remember_token nullable, fillable, hidden .... string(100)
  created_at nullable, fillable ........ datetime / datetime
  updated_at nullable, fillable ........ datetime / datetime
  type appended .................................. attribute

  Relations ................................................
  profile HasOne .................... App\Models\UserProfile
  companies BelongsToMany ............... App\Models\Company
  groups BelongsToMany .................... App\Models\Group
  page MorphOne ............................ App\Models\Page
  articles MorphMany .................... App\Models\Article
  notifications MorphMany  Illuminate\Notifications\DatabaseNotification
```

**Company:**

```
  App\Models\Company .......................................
  Database ........................................... mysql
  Table .......................................... companies

  Attributes ................................... type / cast
  id unique ..................................... string(36)
  name fillable ................................. string(60)
  description nullable, fillable ............... text(65535)
  created_at nullable, fillable ........ datetime / datetime
  updated_at nullable, fillable ........ datetime / datetime
  type appended .................................. attribute

  Relations ................................................
  page MorphOne ............................ App\Models\Page
  articles MorphMany .................... App\Models\Article
```

**Group:**

```
  App\Models\Group .........................................
  Database ........................................... mysql
  Table ............................................. groups

  Attributes ................................... type / cast
  id unique ..................................... string(36)
  name fillable ................................. string(60)
  description nullable, fillable ............... text(65535)
  created_at nullable, fillable ........ datetime / datetime
  updated_at nullable, fillable ........ datetime / datetime
  type appended .................................. attribute

  Relations ................................................
  page MorphOne ............................ App\Models\Page
  articles MorphMany .................... App\Models\Article
```

These models use the following `HasArticles` Trait:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Traits;

use App\Models\Article;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany;

trait HasArticles
{
    /**
     * Return model's articles.
     *
     * @return MorphMany
     */
    public function articles(): MorphMany
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Article::class, 'articleable');
    }
}
```

**Article**

```
  App\Models\Article .......................................
  Database ........................................... mysql
  Table ........................................... articles

  Attributes ................................... type / cast
  id unique ..................................... string(36)
  articleable_type fillable .................... string(255)
  articleable_id fillable ....................... string(36)
  title fillable ................................ string(70)
  content fillable .................................... text
  image_url nullable, fillable ................. string(255)
  created_at nullable, fillable ........ datetime / datetime
  updated_at nullable, fillable ........ datetime / datetime

  Relations ................................................
```

The `Article` model has the following `MorphTo` relationship:

```
public function articleable(): MorphTo
{
    return $this->morphTo(__FUNCTION__, 'articleable_type', 'articleable_id');
}
```

My `create_articles_table` migration (up Schema):

```
Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id')->primary();
    $table->uuidMorphs('articleable');
    $table->string('title', '70');
    $table->longText('content');
    $table->string('image_url')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I am debugging in a Controller using the following:

```
$articles = Article::query()
    ->with('articleable')
    ->inRandomOrder()
    ->first();

dd($articles, $articles->articleable?->toArray());
```

Am I missing something? Thanks for your help.

Env:

```
PHP: 8.1
Laravel: 9.22
Nginx
MariaDB 10.7.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the solution was to not use `\Str::uuid()` (which uses `Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid::uuid4()`) to create my models' UUID, but to use `Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid::uuid6()` instead. No more issues, everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to separate the first() method from the with('articleable'), i have chek up and it looks like modify the query in some way. Instead of with() use the load after that you have the result.

```
$articles = Article::query()
    ->inRandomOrder()
    ->first();
$articles->load('articleable');// try to add a check if $articles return null
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to change anything. Article::query()->inRandomOrder()->limit(50)->get(), then: $articles->load('articleable'); and some relations are still null (my VueJS is crashing: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'type'))

Also tried to dd the collection, the result is the same, the relation is missing (not a Vue problem)

Comment: Do you have the ID of one of those cases, and, did you add the public $incrementing = false; to the company, group and user models, laravel will try to cast as integer all ids if you not, check if always happens to the same articles, also you can check the matcher function, cause something weird is happening when try to match the articles results with your morp models.

Comment: try using \Log::info($articles); instead of dd($articles); this way you can see the results on your laravel.log and it wont stop your application, then copy your json result and open it with this page http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ pasting only the result.